# How to write Makefiles to get a relative path in debug symbols?

Tags: debugging, gcc, makefile, gdb, debug-symbols

I have a structure of code like this:

```
project_dir/
    source1.c
    subdir/
        source2.c
```

The `Makefile` calls `subdir/Makefile`, so that the file `subdir/source2.c` is compiled in this way:

```
gcc -g -someoptions source2.c
```

and symbols in GDB link to `source2.c` instead of `subdir/source2.c` (with the result that GDB can not find symbols in source files). How should I write a Makefile or what options to use in gcc to get symbols using the relative path to the project main directory (or eventually the absolute path)?

I can not use:

```
cd .. && gcc -g -someoptions ../subdir/source2.c
```

because I would have to change references to header files in all files in `subdir`.

Comment: Does the program run normally (without GDB)?

Comment: I call program from gdbserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is platform-specific (e.g. on Linux GDB should just work(TM), so I assume you are *not* on Linux).

One option is to build like this:

```
gcc -g ${PWD}/source2.c -o ...
```

Another option is to use GDB `dir` command to add `${TOP}/project_dir/subdir` to the list of directories that GDB will search for sources.

Comment: I work on Linux, but my program run on ARM processor and I use gdb-arm. I used the `dir` command and it solved the problem. Thank you.